# Use <a> tag to make a POST

Tags: html, forms, post, tags

I know that I cannot make a POST directly through < a> tag, but can I wrap it in a form, like:

```
<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="key1" />
    <a href="/url1" onclick="submit()">key1</a>

    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="key2" />
    <a href="/url2" onclick="submit()">key2</a>

</form>
```

In this way, when I click on the url1, how can the form make a POST with the value='key1'? Thank you very much!

Comment: This isn't a question... it's a post. An appropriate format would be to pose a question and then answer it yourself... or to find a question for which this is an answer and add it as an answer.

Comment: Possibly related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: use 2 separate forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking either of the `<a>`s will POST both keys. The simplest solution is to have two `<form>`s. Here:

```
<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="key1" />
    <a href="/url1" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">key1</a>

</form>

<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="key2" />
    <a href="/url2" onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">key2</a>

</form>
```

Alternatively, you can do the following to submit the forms:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function s(x)
 {
   x.parentNode.submit();
 }
</script>

<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="key1" />
    <a href="/url1" onclick="s(this)">key1</a>

</form>

<form action="theUrl" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="key2" />
    <a href="/url2" onclick="s(this)">key2</a>

</form>
```

Comment: Proper usage for `submit()` is `formObject.submit()`. I've updated the answer with the fix.

Comment: The browser got an error: this.parentNode.submit is not a function

Comment: Try removing the `this.`, maybe that'll work. If that fails you, have a look at my update.

Answer (score 0):

Call js function in onclick of a tag. And then submit the form inside the function.

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="submitform()">

    <script type="text/javascript">  
       function submitform()  {
          document.formName.submit();
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there would be tens of such < a> tags, I cannot write js functions for each of them, how can I make it?

Comment: write one js function and pass form-name as parameter in every <a> tag onclick function call.